# PowerShell_copy-item_ToSession/FromSession

Tags: powershell-4.0

I want to copy a file from the remote server to local, and my code is

1. Make sure the xxx.xxx.x.xxx's connection

>

```
Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString |  ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File"C:\Users\chrishchang\Desktop\powershell/remote-password.txt"

$user = get-content C:\Users\chrishchang\Desktop\powershell/remote-user.txt

$pass = get-content C:\Users\chrishchang\Desktop\powershell/remote-password.txt |
ConvertTo-securestring

&myCred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$pass

$session = new-pssession -computername name -credential $myCred

Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxx.xxx.x.xxx -ScriptBlock { ipconfig /all } -credential $myCred
```

2. create the new file

>

```
$command={New-Item c:\scripts\new_file.txt -type file -force -value "This is text added to the file"}
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock $command
```

3. copy the file from xxx.xxx.x.xxx to local

>

```
$command={Copy-Item -FromSession $session -Path "c:\scripts\new_file.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\chrishchang\desktop\"}

Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock $command
```

4. The error result..
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emNKf.png)

Please give me some suggestion, I have suffered from it for a long  time.

Answer (score 0):

The last step (3) should be:

```
Copy-Item -FromSession $session -Path "c:\scripts\new_file.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\chrishchang\desktop"
```

Don't use Invoke-Command as the Copy-Item already uses the session.